# Route traffic on laptop's wired connection through to Wifi (Windows 7)?

Tags: networking, windows-7

My Windows 7 laptop connects to the network via WIFI.  I also have a wired connection to my Linux box.  Can I configure the laptop so that traffic from the Linux box is routed through the wired connection on the laptop to it's WIFI connection?

TY,
Fred

Comment: Hi Fred,

This question might be better suited for superuser.com

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can create a network bridge between both network connections.

Check out:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Create-a-network-bridge

Make sure you select both connections by holding down the control key and clicking on them. Depending on your network adapter, you may also have to use a crossover cable between your Linux box and Windows PC for connectivity.

-Matt